# Java execute code on parameter annotation

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations

I am very new to Java annotations. But, how I understand is that they can't run any code them selves.

I am trying to make a validation package and would like to use the `@valid` parameter annotation to validate an object.
Example:

```
public Response login(@valid LoginRequest request) {
    return ...
}
```

I would like it to work this way, it is the same way as in spring validating.

So my question is: How can I execute code on the `@valid` annotation to validate an object? I don't mind if the solution would only work with spring.

The reason I want to make my own validation package is because I want to have a more "laravel like" validation package.

Comment: Your last comment is wrong - of course it does. I would suggest that you RTFM rather than attempting to implement things that are obviously beyond you.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm sorry, I removed it ;). But it doesn't support it in a way I can connect to to a field, and I have to create a whole new annotation to create an customer validator.

Comment: The point of Java is that it's fully type safe. If you want dynamic language features, use a dynamic language - PHP for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was pretty easy. I just had to create an interceptor and check in the `preHandle` if there was an handler parameter that had the `@valid` annotation.

If `@valid` was present I could get the object and validate it, when failed just throw an exception and handle the exception with the exception handler.

I didn't know that I could access controller parameters from an interceptor...